# Adding and removing class active on scroll is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a programmer beginner and I came across witch this problem. My script is not adding or removing class "active" in my navigation bar. Can someone help me please?

My script:

```
$('nav a').on('click', function() {

  var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
    scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - 28;

  $('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollPoint
  }, 500);

  return false;

})


$(window).scroll(function() {
  var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (windscroll >= 100) {
    $('nav').addClass('fixed');
    $('.wrapper section').each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - 20) {
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');
      }
    });

  } else {

    $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
    $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
    $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
  }

}).scroll();
```

My HTML code example:

```
<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-scroll="home">Hlavní stránka</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-scroll="rooms">Naše pokoje</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-scroll="prizes">Ceník</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-scroll="footer">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- Banner -->
<section id="banner">
  <header style="background-color: transparent;">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
  </header>
</section>

<!-- Main -->
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="12u">

        <!-- rooms -->
        <section id="rooms" data-anchor="rooms">
          <header class="major">
            <h2>Naše pokoje a prostory</h2>
          </header>¨
```

The class active is stuck at "Hlavní stránka".

Comment: `$('.wrapper section')` - I don't see any items that satisfy this selector, as none of your elements have a class `wrapper`. Additionally, because your elements are quite nested, you may be better off using `offset().top` instead of `position().top`.

Comment: I just edited something and it seems to be working fine only if the page is height enough.